# Signing .jar file with a .cer file

Tags: java, applet, code-signing

I'm trying to sign a jar file with a code signing certificate issued by globalsign.

I'm completely new to this but after some googling and a lot of trial and error, I executed the following steps.

I've imported the certificate in my keystore using:

```
keytool -importcert -alias signalias -file OS200912023195.cer
```

When I try to sign my jar file using:

```
jarsigner applet.jar signalias
```

I get the following error:

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: signalias.  signalias must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Did I forget something or lies the problem with the certificate?

Comment: How is it going? Have you succeeded to sign the jar yet?

Comment: No not yet, I´m giving it another try today. Thanks for your input. I´ll keep you updated and will accept an answer within 4 days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...I'm wondering if I maybe need something more than just a cer file?...

@Mark I guess you're right. As I can remember, the exception type like

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: signalias. signalias must
>   reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and
>   corresponding public key certificate chain.

... makes me think you trying to sign jar with cert only. So you must be skipped some important steps :|

The first thing you have to do if you want to use certificate is to gen [CSR](http://www.sslshopper.com/what-is-a-csr-certificate-signing-request.html)...

- A) gen keystore; then gen the public/private key in the keystore. Command like a

> keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks
>   -keysize 2048

- B) then gen CSR - for more information you can read [this](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=AR185&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US). Command like a

> keytool -certreq -alias mydomain -keystore keystore.jks -file
>   mydomain.csr

- C) for more detailed info about keytool common commands you can read [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

if you are OK with OpenSSL then gen your own cert as follows step D...

- D) In the case you need to have a self-signed certificate you can
  follow [these](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) steps...

...back to your keystore

- E) only after then you to **import** the cert to your keystore with command like

> keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file server.crt -keystore
>   keystore.jks

- F) And only then you can use **[jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/jarsigner.html)** tool to sign your jar

---

Comment if that helps

Comment: I made every step you described (with self-signed cert), but receive the same error 'Certificate chain not found for...'. Is it possible to generate valid self-signed certificate at all, to fool Java ???

Comment: hi @user592704 could you help with this similar question on signing an applet ... we don't know whether to use the private key or the code signing certificate we received through a thawte reseller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416200/is-this-code-signing-certificate-valid-for-signing-applets

Answer (score 2):

`.cer` files never store private keys, and to sign a `JAR` you need to have a private key in your keystore. So I guess, you need to find out where the private key of your certificate is, and add it to your keystore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I create the keystore myself or should the jks file come with the certificate?

Comment: You can import the private key in your keystore, but first, you should get the private key. Private keys are usually distributed in pkcs12 (`.p12`) keystores. Contact your certificate provider and ask, where is the PK.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use the below command to verify the keystore for your imported certificate.

keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias

if the details are found to be correct, there seems to be an issue with the certificate provided. It is incomplete.

Comment: The details shown seem to be correct and still valid, in the past another .jar file is apparently signed with the same .cer file. I'm wondering if I maybe need something more than just a cer file

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:
[Java tutorial - Signing JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html)

Also, check out [the page referenced from the above tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/cert3.html)

Answer (score 0):

> jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: signalias. signalias must
>   reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and
>   corresponding public key certificate chain.

I got that error when I created my Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using an openssl command instead of using keytool.  The result is that when I generated my keystore, it didn't contain the private key, only the certificate that I had imported.

This post fixed my problem: [Can a Java key store import a key pair generated by OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685512/can-a-java-key-store-import-a-key-pair-generated-by-openssl)

After creating the key and the certificate with OpenSSL, use OpenSSL to create a PKCS #12 key store:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem > server.p12

Then convert this store into a Java key store:

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -destkeystore
>   server.jks -srcstoretype pkcs12